# What path should i add for excel data for selenium test in jenkins

Tags: excel, selenium, docker, jenkins

I have written selenium scripts which takes data from excel sheet and pass it to the URL. This works perfectly in my host machine.

Now I need to run this in Jenkins which is running on docker container. Now, what path should I add where excel file is located for the test. because when I run Jenkins job I get an error as "No such file in directory"

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you copy the excel file to the container and used WORKDIR in your Dockerfile to enter that dir before the command is executed?

Comment: How are you trying to run your selenium scripts using Jenkins?

Comment: @JRichardsz by creating runnable jar and adding related lib

Answer (score 0):

you should be using an absolute path to the file

See a python example.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'file.xls')

file = pd.read_excel(abs_file_path)
print(file.head())
```